# echo works twice just for one id but doesn't for the other one

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, echo

There are 2 entries on the table. But it echos 3 entries but it echos twice one of them. If i change it to ASC from DESC, then it echos the other one twice. If i use "where id <> 5" then it just echos id 6 just once. But it is a dynamic site so... And i use the same exact code on another page and it works. Here is the full code:

```
<?php
$cek = mysql_query('select id,isim,aciklama,tarih from galeri where dil = '.$dbDil.' order by id desc');
while($kaynak = mysql_fetch_assoc($cek)){
    $cekG = mysql_query('select resim_url from galeriresim where galeriID = '.$kaynak['id'].' order by id desc');
    $galeri .= '<h1 class="sayfaBaslik fl"><span>'.$kaynak['tarih'].'</span> '.$kaynak['isim'].'</h1>';
    $galeri .= '<h2 class="sayfaAciklama fl">'.$kaynak['aciklama'].'</h2>';
    $galeri .= '<div class="sayfaIcerik" style="width:100%">';
    $galeri .= '<div class="galeriH fl swiper-container-'.$kaynak['id'].'">';
    $galeri .= '<ul class="fl swiper-wrapper-'.$kaynak['id'].'">';
    while($kaynakG = mysql_fetch_assoc($cekG)){
           $galeri .= '<li class="swiper-slide-'.$kaynak['id'].'"><img src="'.$yol.'images/galeri/'.$kaynak['id'].'/'.$kaynakG['resim_url'].'" /></li>';
    }
    $galeri .= '</ul></div></div>';
    $galeri .='<script>';
    $galeri .= 'var mySwiper = new Swiper(\'.swiper-container-'.$kaynak['id'].'\',{';
    $galeri .= 'moveStartThreshold : 75,';
    $galeri .= 'wrapperClass : "swiper-wrapper-'.$kaynak['id'].'",';
    $galeri .= 'slideClass : "swiper-slide-'.$kaynak['id'].'"';
    $galeri .= '});';
    $galeri .= '</script>';
    echo $galeri;
}       
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing your final echo **INSIDE** the main while() loop:

```
while(..) {
   while(..) { .. }
   echo ..
}
```

It should be

```
while(..) {
   while(..) { .. }
}
echo ..
```

Since you're echoing INSIDE the main loop, you'll be running that echo multiple times, spitting out `$galeri` as it's being built.

Comment: It works thanks. Btw, i use it inside the while loop and it works on another page. Is it a problem to use it like that? Because i want it to echo one by one.

Comment: then you need to reset the variable so it's empty on each loop, because right now you just keep adding on to it, and echoing out the entire thing each time. e.g. put `$galeri = '';` at the start of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
i have added mysq_free_result and echo must be outside the while !

```
<?php
    $cek = mysql_query('select id,isim,aciklama,tarih from galeri where dil = '.$dbDil.' order by id desc');
    while($kaynak = mysql_fetch_assoc($cek)){
        $cekG = mysql_query('select resim_url from galeriresim where galeriID = '.$kaynak['id'].' order by id desc');
        $galeri .= '<h1 class="sayfaBaslik fl"><span>'.$kaynak['tarih'].'</span> '.$kaynak['isim'].'</h1>';
        $galeri .= '<h2 class="sayfaAciklama fl">'.$kaynak['aciklama'].'</h2>';
        $galeri .= '<div class="sayfaIcerik" style="width:100%">';
        $galeri .= '<div class="galeriH fl swiper-container-'.$kaynak['id'].'">';
        $galeri .= '<ul class="fl swiper-wrapper-'.$kaynak['id'].'">';
        while($kaynakG = mysql_fetch_assoc($cekG)){
               $galeri .= '<li class="swiper-slide-'.$kaynak['id'].'"><img src="'.$yol.'images/galeri/'.$kaynak['id'].'/'.$kaynakG['resim_url'].'" /></li>';
        }
        mysql_free_result($cekG);
        $cekG ="";
        $galeri .= '</ul></div></div>';
        $galeri .='<script>';
        $galeri .= 'var mySwiper = new Swiper(\'.swiper-container-'.$kaynak['id'].'\',{';
        $galeri .= 'moveStartThreshold : 75,';
        $galeri .= 'wrapperClass : "swiper-wrapper-'.$kaynak['id'].'",';
        $galeri .= 'slideClass : "swiper-slide-'.$kaynak['id'].'"';
        $galeri .= '});';
        $galeri .= '</script>';

    }    
     echo $galeri;   
    ?>
```

Comment: care to explain/expound on what is different in your code vs the OPs code?

Comment: @Sean i added two additional lines.

Comment: Answers are better if you add the explanation with code you recommend adding/changing in the body of the answer, instead of just stating `Try this...`, or just in a comment after.

Comment: It also works, thanks. But i didn't need "mysql_free_result" because the project itself is not that big. Using it doesn't have any downside though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JOIN`ed query then you wouldn't need a double while loop. you shouldnt be using mysql anyway. Use mysqli or pdo

```
'select g.id,g.isim,g.aciklama,g.tarih, gr.resim_url
  from galeri g 
  JOIN galeriresim gr on gr.galeriID = g.id
  where g.dil = '.$dbDil.' order by id desc'
```

Comment: I'm learning them. But now, i need to use mysql because i don't feel i'm ready to use. Thanks for advice.